Dockerized Blazor app cannot find static web assets of NuGet package
I'm trying to run docker for the Blazor app and I utilize MudBlazor. When I run app with 'latest' tag, it works as expected. However, running with 'dev' tag causes an error saying:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll: '/root/.nuget/packages/mudblazor/7.11.0/staticwebassets/'
Docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000

USER app
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG configuration=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/eUsta.Blazor.Web/eUsta.Blazor.Web.csproj", "src/eUsta.Blazor.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/eUsta.Blazor.Web/eUsta.Blazor.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/eUsta.Blazor.Web"
RUN dotnet build "eUsta.Blazor.Web.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG configuration=Release
RUN dotnet publish "eUsta.Blazor.Web.csproj" -c $configuration -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "eUsta.Blazor.Web.dll"]

Command that VS Code runs for debug-mode:
docker container run --detach --tty --name "eusta-dev" --publish-all --mount "type=bind,source=<path-to-project>/src/eUsta.Blazor.Web,destination=/app" --mount "type=bind,source=<path-to-project>\eUsta,destination=/src" --mount "type=bind,source=<path-to-vsdbg>\.vsdbg,destination=/remote_debugger,readonly" --mount "type=bind,source=<path-to-nuget>\.nuget\packages,destination=/root/.nuget/packages,readonly" --mount "type=bind,source=<path-to-nuget>\packages,destination=/home/appuser/.nuget/packages,readonly" --mount "type=bind,source=<path-to-nuget>\.nuget\packages,destination=/home/app/.nuget/packages,readonly" --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio-code" --env "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" --env "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" --entrypoint "/bin/sh" eusta:dev
I cannot find what is wrong here. Can someone help? If you need any other information, please, let me know.
I've clean & build app, tried to publish newly built app to docker.

I'm seeing the same issue. The app user that's created does not have access to the root folder where the nuget packages are mounted. To get around this I commented out the creation of the app user so that it runs as root. Not ideal but I don't know enough to figure out why the base template generated dockerfile in vscode would make a dockerfile with this error. Or perhaps it's something missing in the launch task.
